# Cross over from left scene to right scene

Tags: editing, davinci-resolve

I found an interesting video that show two clips merge and blend so it looks like one video but two different scenes because the guys from the left scene can cross over to the right scene.

[image: The guys cross over to the right scene]

In the left image, part of the body of the guy from the left scene is disappear because it is covered by the right scene.

In the right image, all of those guys can cross over to the right scene and nothing is disappear in the right scene (the wall and the person).

Here is the link of the video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y98wt7n_lSbguiA0dYaO44gJ_j_6lcyj/view?usp=sharing

I use keyword such transition, transform, merge, and blending to search for tutorial but no luck. What is the name of this technique? Does black-magic design software has features to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two parts to this technique.

The first one is sometimes called a “split screen” or “side by side” video technique. Pretty much any NLE “like Davinci Resolve will allow you to achieve this effect. The primary thing to make this technique work, is how you shoot the two video clips. Once you’ve shot them, you’ll simply crop or mask one to fill only half of the screen and then place the second one on a layer below it. Here’s a link to a video tutorial on how to make a split video:

The second part is called rotoscoping. This is where an object (or person) from one clip "enters" the other video. There's a couple video tutorials for rotoscoping in Davinci Resolve:

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. If you watch the attached video, in the beginning, you will see those guys moving around and disappear behind the clip on the right. it is the easy one because you only need to merge two clips and put half of the right clip on top of the left clip. but since the 5th second you will see them move around in front of the clip on the right. it is not easy for me.

Comment: @Xelonovia That's called rotoscoping, I've updated my answer to include some info on that.

Comment: Thank you, rotoscope is the keyword that I'm looking for.